# samsung kies 2 won't connect to my samsung galaxy 1

Tags: windows-7, drivers, phone

I previously had some problems with Samsung kies but I eventually could get it working:
https://superuser.com/questions/411760/how-to-enable-my-samsung-kies
https://superuser.com/questions/442904/cant-connect-galaxy-1-to-samsung-kies-that-used-to-work
Now I got problems again. After an update for a Kies installation that used to work, the phone (Galaxy 1) won't connect and after disconnecting and starting the troubleshooting it doesn't go anywhere when I press start:

[image]

Pressing start at the above dialog doesn't do anything. It used to reinstall the driver which solved my problem before. What do you think I should do about this? Is Samsung Kies a buggy software or why is it behaving so unpredictable?

### Update

I reinstalled everything and then today it is working but it was not working this morning:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check the connectivity between your mobile and computer. Are you connecting from Wifi? If you are comfortable with some advanced settings, go to your phone settings and check the ip-address. Now ping this address from your computer to test connectivity.

As for me, I've never used the additional layer imposed by kies. I directly open the samsung-app store and browse internet by using my computer as a proxy server. This way you won't need kies any more!

Comment: Today it Kies is working for me but it wasn't this morning. I'm updating the question with more info. Thank you for the answer.